# Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference.Equals(obj) behaviour

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

What fields does this method use to compare the objects? 
I need a simple method to determine if two different instances of EntityReference are referencing to the same entity. And I don't want to reinvent a bicycle if Equals() method fits my needs.

The MSDN says only that Equals returns:

> true if the specified EntityReference is equal to the EntityReference
>   object; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 5):

Partial experiments showed that Equals method compares 'Id' and 'LogicalName' fields and ignores 'Name'. But we didn't test all possible cases (there are some more fields in EntityReference).

[image]

Comment: Are you supposed to use id2 for ref2 ??

Comment: No. There are no mistakes, Sorry, i just forgot to remove id2. We are intending to have an equal Ids, but different LogicalNames in the second testcase. There should be the third testcase, but it's obvious that different Ids should result in 'false' output from the Equals(...)

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN for EntityReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference.aspx) showing 6 Properties (fields), out of which only 3 - **Id** (Primary Key GUID), **Name** (Display Value / Primary attribute) and **Logical Name** (Entity Name) are desirable.

Also **Name** is nullable property, let’s say for example: targetentity in Plugin will bring it as null whereas preimage will bring the value from DB. The other 3 - RowVersion, KeyAttributes & ExtensionData are Metadata.

[EntityReference.Equals(Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326148.aspx) is overridden from [Object.Equals(Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) which says:

> Notes for Callers
>   Derived classes frequently override the Object.Equals(Object) method to implement value equality. In addition, types also frequently provide an additional strongly typed overload to the Equals method, typically by implementing the IEquatable interface. When you call the Equals method to test for equality, you should know whether the current instance overrides Object.Equals and understand how a particular call to an Equals method is resolved. Otherwise, you may be performing a test for equality that is different from what you intended, and the method may return an unexpected value.

Hence, the overridden Equals method consider only **Id** to decide the same Entity”record”, and **LogicalName** to decide the same Entity “type” when [equate](http://www.crmcodex.com/2011/12/tip-use-equals-instead-of-for-crm-type-comparison/).